# Gaussian Mixture Model: ValueError: pvals < 0, pvals > 1 or pvals contains NaNs

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I'm struggling to sample from a Gaussian Mixture Model. I have a very simple example where there's actually only one component (so, not actually a mixture). Then I fit it using standard normal data. However, the mixture's weights end up being greater than 1 for the one mixture, causing an error:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

dataset = np.random.standard_normal(10).reshape(-1, 1)
mixture = GaussianMixture(n_components=1)
mixture.fit(dataset)
mixture.sample(10)
```

```
ValueError: pvals < 0, pvals > 1 or pvals contains NaNs
```

It's evident to me that this is caused by the weights of the first component being greater than 1:

```
> print(mixture.weights_[0])
1.0000000000000002
```

This kind of seems like a bug. But maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although *technically* this seems to be a bug indeed, truth is that, as already explained in the other answer, the real issue stems from the fact that asking for a Gaussian Mixture with `n_components=1` does not make sense from a *modelling* perspective; one could argue that an exception (or at least a warning) should be caused earlier, i.e. whenever a `GaussianMixture(n_components=1)` is requested. I guess it may be a design choice not to do so, but in any case this is arguably something to be discussed in the scikit-learn Github repo as a possible issue, and not here.

That said, a workaround here is pretty straighforward: in the special case when `n_components=1`, *force* `mixture.weights_[0]` to be equal to 1.0:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

dataset = np.random.standard_normal(10).reshape(-1, 1)
mixture = GaussianMixture(n_components=1)
mixture.fit(dataset)

mixture.weights_[0]
# 1.0000000000000002

mixture.sample(10)
# ValueError: pvals < 0, pvals > 1 or pvals contains NaNs

# force weight to 1.0:
mixture.weights_[0] = 1.

mixture.sample(10)
# result:
(array([[ 0.51371178],
        [ 0.1530927 ],
        [-0.56327362],
        [-1.22308348],
        [ 1.26889771],
        [ 1.11849849],
        [-1.47091749],
        [-0.41259178],
        [ 1.93872769],
        [ 0.26282224]]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

Apparently, there should not be any theoretical concerns here, since *by definition* the weight of a single component in a Gaussian mixture is 1.0; it is just that, as demonstrated in the other answer, in the limit of a low number of available samples, the GMM algorithm fails to give a weight of exactly 1.0 within the available machine precision.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a bug, first of all, if you are using a gaussian mixture there should be more than 1 component. If you want to sample from a normal distribution distribution, you can fit a normal distribution and then sample from it. Using a GMM is unnecessary.

You get that error because at one point it estimates the responsibility, weights and adds 10* machine precision for float to it, from the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py#L249) for initializing weights

```
nk = resp.sum(axis=0) + 10 * np.finfo(resp.dtype).eps
```

If the number of samples is too low, and you have only 1 sample you end up with weights > 1. A GMM would normally run a E and M step, but in the n=1 case, there's no M step to run to estimate the weights again, so it stays like this.

The part where this goes wrong is at [line 653-655 source code for GMM](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py#L653). We can reproduce it here:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_array, check_random_state
n_components = 1

random_state = check_random_state(42)
resp = random_state.rand(n_samples,n_components)
resp /= resp.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

from sklearn.mixture._gaussian_mixture import _estimate_gaussian_covariances_full, _estimate_gaussian_parameters

weights, means, covariances = _estimate_gaussian_parameters(
            dataset, resp, 1e-06, "full")
weights /= n_samples

weights[0]
Out[90]: 1.0000000000000002
```

Again, it is not meant for this, if you would really have to do it with GMM function, you can see with a larger n it gets over the machine precision:

```
dataset = np.random.standard_normal(50).reshape(-1, 1)
mixture = GaussianMixture(n_components=1)
mixture.fit(dataset)
mixture.sample(10)

(array([[ 2.09871131],
        [-0.25002264],
        [-2.50289153],
        [ 0.23199507],
        [-1.12191031],
        [-1.8197654 ],
        [ 0.66417858],
        [-1.07637344],
        [ 0.56829766],
        [ 0.62341029]]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it still seems like a bug to me. The purpose of my model is that it should transparently work with 1 or more components, allowing the user to customize the model's complexity. I don't want to have to write a completely different code path for 1 component.

Comment: @Migwell FWIW, I will agree with the answer (+1 for the in-depth investigation). Please keep in mind that the purpose of your *programming* approach does not necessarily mean that it makes sense from a *modeling* perspective (and here it does not, indeed).

Comment: You don't consider it a bug if a certain parameter value supported by the API (`n_components=1`) causes an exception?

Comment: @Migwell *technically* yes (see own answer); but since you asked "*maybe I'm doing something wrong here?*" the answer is also yes, you are doing something wrong from a *modelling* perspective. Arguably it would not make much difference for your stated purpose if an exception was thrown earlier, i.e. in the `GaussianMixture(n_components=1)` part.